# Collada file size

Tags: export, collada

I am a hardened cinema 4d user and am using blender to bring in fbx files and export out as collada using the open collada engine within blender.

My problem is I have a 20meg c4d file, a 20meg fbx file and when saved in blender again a 20meg file, yet when I export the collarda the file is 80meg!!

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: I'm quite sure that is usual to have a collada file bigger than his fbx because it is designed to be supported by a very wide range of software packages. Are you sure that is this a Blender related problem? Did you try to convert your file with other softwares? What are their output size?

Comment: Good point, exporting from C4d to collada results in a file size of 44 meg, whilst still a increase in size no where as bad as blender.